# PyBytes_AS_STRING unexpected output

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to embed python with c++. The following is the code written in c++. The code should return "hello_world" as output. But PyBytes_AS_STRING is not returning "hello_world". I'm using python 3.5 version and trying to compile the code in visual studio.

```
string myfunc(char * inp)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue1;
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString("mod1");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "func1");
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    pValue1 = PyUnicode_FromString(inp);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue1);
    PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    if (pResult == NULL)
        printf("Calling the python method failed.\n");
    string result = PyBytes_AS_STRING(pResult);
    cout << result << endl;
    Py_Finalize();
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << myfunc("hello_world") << endl;
}
```

mod1.py:

```
def func1(inp):
    return inp
```

Comment: And what's the exact error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: It is not giving any error. It is printing garbage value.

Comment: you need to call PyErr_Occurred() after each line and check for null pointer returns. Also you should stop if pResult is null and not try and print after that - that will give garbage results. Your error is likely earlier